# Making sense of asyncio.as_completed()

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Imagine a simple program like this, using which I'm getting a field of data from multiple pages of json data available through an api gateway. (Sorry I couldn't find a free json api that supports pagination to make the example completely reproducable.)

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def fetch(url, params = None):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, params) as response:
            return await response.json()

async def get_all_pages(base_url):
    def paginate(size=10**6):
        limit = 100
        offset = 0
        while offset <= size:
            yield {"offset": offset, "limit": limit}
            offset += limit
    total = (await fetch(base_url))["data"]["total"] # total number of pages
    coroutines = [fetch(base_url, params) for params in paginate(total)]
    print("total number of pages: {}, total number of coroutines: {}".format(total, len(coroutines))
    for routine in asyncio.as_completed(coroutines):
        r = await routine
        yield r["data"]["field"] #a field in the data for each page

async def main():
    url = "http://arandomurl.com"
    results = []
    async for x in get_all_pages(url):
        results.append(x)

    print(len(results)) #returns 1 -> only the first element is returned

asyncio.run(main())
```

The problem is that the for loop in my `main` function only retrieves the first element of my generator, somehow the generator stops after publishing the first element. Which means that `as_completed` is not working as I thought it would work in `def_get_all_pages`: Publishing the results of the completed coroutines and then passing it to the `yield r["data"]["field"]`. line. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: `page_data = await x`  Is `x` awaitable object ?

Comment: @AlexNoname I think since the result of get_all_pages is an async object, it should be awaited deosn't it? I'm really confused by asyncio's terminology in general.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken `x` is value from json  `r["data"]["field"]`. `await x` should raise exception.

Comment: @AlexNoname yes yes you are right! this is a problem of trying to come up with a minimal example. I edited it.

Comment: Please add `print` for `total` and `len(coroutines)`

Comment: @AlexNoname done what you asked.

Comment: I'm confused.  Your code creates one coroutine for every 100 pages - assuming that r["data"]["total"] is the number of pages.  Each coroutine fetches exactly one item, r["data"]["field"], not one item per page.  The number of items in `results` will not be the number of pages, but the number of pages divided by 100.  I changed your program by replacing fetch with a function that simply returns a hard-coded dictionary (avoiding aiohttp calls), and it all worked fine.  What am I missing?

Comment: @PaulCornelius could you share your program here? Every page I get, I extract a field from the response that shows that I'm a page next. It's arbitrary just to show pagination nothing more.

Comment: I posted it as an answer.  It's a program similar to yours but it can run stand-alone without internet access.  Perhaps you can look it over and explain again what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a test program I wrote.  I took the code posted in the question and replaced the guts of the function "fetch" to return a dictionary.  With this change I can actually run the program, and it works.  I get one item in "results" for every 100 "pages."

```
import asyncio

async def fetch(_url, params = None):
    if params is None:
        return {"data": {"total": 169}}
    return {"data": {"field" : str(params)}}

async def get_all_pages(base_url):
    def paginate(size=10**6):
        limit = 100
        offset = 0
        while offset <= size:
            yield {"offset": offset, "limit": limit}
            offset += limit
    total = (await fetch(base_url))["data"]["total"] # total number of pages
    coroutines = [fetch(base_url, params) for params in paginate(total)]
    print("total number of pages: {}, total number of coroutines: {}".format(
        total, len(coroutines)))
    for routine in asyncio.as_completed(coroutines):
        r = await routine
        yield r["data"]["field"] #a field in the data for each page

async def main():
    url = "http://arandomurl.com"
    results = []
    async for x in get_all_pages(url):
        results.append(x)

    print(results) #returns 1 -> only the first element is returned

asyncio.run(main())
```